# SQL Group by Day of Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012.  I have a view that has two fields - Machine Date and Total Mins.  The view is only showing data from the previous week - this works fine.  I then have another view based on this view using the below SQL:

```
SELECT        
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Sunday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Sun, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Monday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Mon, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Tuesday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Tues, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Wednesday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Wed, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Thursday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Thursday, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Friday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Friday, 
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Saturday' THEN [Total Mins] END AS Sat
FROM
    dbo.vw_Machine_Minutes_Overview
```

However, the results are not on one line, they increase with each day of the week i.e.

```
Sun    Mon   Tues   Wed  Thurs  Fri   Sat
10     
       15
              25
                    20
                          21
                                12
```

But I need the results to show like this:

```
Sun    Mon   Tues   Wed  Thurs  Fri   Sat
10     15     25    20    21    12
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server pivot query`.

Comment: I don't follow - I'm not using the PIVOT command?

Comment: @Michael that pivot command does this all in one go (kind of) i have posted an answer for you to have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Sunday' THEN [Total Mins] END) AS Sun,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, MachineMidLineDate) = 'Monday' THEN [Total Mins] END) AS Mon,
      . . . 
FROM dbo.vw_Machine_Minutes_Overview;
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment about using pviot is another way to do it:

Working example:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/749735/930554/pivot-data-by-day-of-week-from-date-field

I find the syntax a bit confusing but this should work:

```
select *
from 
(
select  datepart(dw,[MachineMidLineDate]) as DayOfWeek, [Total Mins]
  from #vw_Machine_Minutes_Overview 
) src
pivot
(
  sum([Total Mins])
  for DayOfWeek in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) piv;
```

The `datepart(dw,[MachineMidLineDate])` part returns a number between 1 and 7 representing the day of the week, that is used to specify the columns in the `[1],[2],[3]...` part of the query.

datepart: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

pivot: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx